# Characters with different repeat times in one group

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem with regular expression like this:

```
^[0-9\s{0,1}]{4,}$
```

I want to match that numbers can be set to different repeat time then white space character
in a way that whole expression between [] bracket can be repeated at least four times but white space which can be anywhere in expression can be repeated zero or one time.
I checked the whole regular expression language - quick reference for C# and nothing found.
Please help,

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide sample input that should match and input that should not? Note that `{0,1}` is essentially `?`.

Comment: knittl is right, please post some samples. Honestly don't really know why people doesn't provide them in the regex questions as I think that is the easiest way to show people what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Is 3 digits and a space valid ?

Comment: If you want to match `((one or more digits) followed by zero or one white-space) 4 or more times`, this would even match `1234`. Clarification with samples, you want to match would be great yea.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do this way:

```
^(?=\d*\s?\d*$)(\d\s?){4,}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?=\d*\s?\d*$)(\d\s?){4,}$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                             (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (at least 4 times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                             (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){4,}                    end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Should this match `"1 2 3 4"` ?

Comment: @Jonny5: No it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is invalid:

```
^[0-9\s{0,1}]{4,}$
```

This is the definitione of using square brackets

**Example:**

`[\w'-]` - Matches any word character, single quote, or hyphen, meaning just one of these listed

and adding `{4,}` after it means, **repeat** four or more Times, so basically you repeat matching a digit or white space four or more times, which is probably not what you are looking for.

If you need help with making the pattern please provide me with the sample input and expected result and I'll try to help you.

For now I have came up with following pattern.

**PATTERN**

```
^(\d{4,})$|^(\s\d{3,})$|^(\d{3,}\s)$|^(\d{2,}\s\d+?)$|^(\d+?\s\d{2,})$
```

It captures any number of digits followed by a white space/preceeding by a white space or any number of digits which separated by a single white space.

Answer (score 2):

Puting quantifiers in a character class doesn't make sense. Since it will literally match the following characters `{},01`.

The trick is to use a lookahead with some alternation:

```
^                                      # Begin of string
(?:                                    # Non-capturing group
   [0-9]{4,}                           # Case when there is no white-space
   |                                   # Or
   (?=[0-9]*\s[0-9]*$)[0-9\s]{5,}      # Case when there is one white-space
)                                      # End of non-capturing group
$                                      # End of string
```

The first expression is easy to understand, let's explain the second one:

- `(?=[0-9]*\s[0-9]*$)`  : Make sure there is only digits and only one white space
- `[0-9\s]{5,}` : Match digits and white-spaces 5 or more times. I chose for 5 times, since the OP wants to match *at least 4 digits* and optionally one whitespace. So in this case, if there is a whitespace, we would have at least 5 characters. If there is no whitespace, the first part of the regex would take care of it.